# Pushing & popping objects into an array using JS in Qt

Tags: javascript, arrays, qt, qml

I'm trying to create dynamic objects in qml and save these objects into an array using the `push()` function inside of a JS file, here is my `main.qml` file:

```
import "AidFile.js" as Jsfile

 var c = null
 c = Qt.createComponent("Lines.qml")
 k = c.createObject(gameCanvas)

 k.height = 1
 k.width = grid.spacing
 k.x = image1.x - grid.spacing
 k.y = image1.y + image1.height / 2
 Jsfile.enterKs(k)
 Jsfile.cons()
```

& here is the functions `enterKs` & `cons` in `AidFile.js` file:

```
var t = [];

function enterKs(k) {
t.push(k);
}

function cons(){
    var i = t;
    var tester;

  for (var counter=0; counter<=t.length; counter++){
      tester = i.pop();
      console.log(tester.x);
      console.log(tester.y);

  }

}
```

the thing is everytime i call the `cons` function only x & y of the last object (k) is printed, which indicates that `i` array contains only one element (last one pushed), why is that happening although it should print the x & y of all objects being pushed to the array using `enterKs` function. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you're asking here.  In `main.qml` you call `enterKs()` once.  At that point the `t` array goes from zero to one items.  Then you call `cons()`, which removes the item from the array and prints out the object's `x` and `y` parameters to the console -- but you say you expected more than one item in the array?  Why is that?

Comment: `pop()` changes the size of the array and thus changes the loop. That's probably the problem. Try this instead of a `for`:

`while (t.length) {
        tester = i.pop();
        console.log(tester.x); 
        console.log(tester.y);
    }`
By the way, next time provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)!

Comment: @MrEricSir: thanks for your reply, Actually i'm calling `enterKs()` more than once although i'm showing it only once above, but i'm calling it in other places, so i was expecting x & y of all objecs that has being pushed, @BaCaRoZzo: thanks for your comment & yes i also think the issue is with pop, any idea of other methods that can be used instead of `pop()`.

Comment: @Developer Well, the code I've provided substitute your `for` and it works OK with `pop()`. Did you tested it? Or you don't want to `pop()`  elements any more?